no session created - appwrite
I'm using Appwrite and Next.js and when I try to create a session in my app, no session will be created so the user variable is undefined.
How can I solve this?
appwrite.ts

import { Client, Account, Databases, Users } from "node-appwrite";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export async function createSessionClient() {
  const client = new Client()
    .setEndpoint(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_ENDPOINT!)
    .setProject(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_PROJECT!);

  const session = cookies().get("appwrite-session");

  if (!session || !session.value) {
    throw new Error("No session");
  }

  client.setSession(session.value);

  return {
    get account() {
      return new Account(client);
    },
  };
}

export async function createAdminClient() {
  const client = new Client()
    .setEndpoint(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_ENDPOINT!)
    .setProject(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_PROJECT!)
    .setKey(process.env.NEXT_APPWRITE_KEY!);

  return {
    get account() {
      return new Account(client);
    },
    get database() {
        return new Databases(client)
    },
    get user() {
        return new Users(client)
    }
  };
}


user.actions.ts

'use server';

import { ID } from "node-appwrite"
import { createAdminClient, createSessionClient } from "../appwrite";
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { parseStringify } from "../utils";
export const signIn = async ({ email, password }: signInProps) => {
    try {
        const { account } = await createAdminClient();
        const response = await account.createEmailPasswordSession(email, password)
        return parseStringify(response)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error', error)
    }
}

export const signUp = async (userData: SignUpParams) => {
    const { email, password, firstName, lastName } = userData
    try {
        const { account } = await createAdminClient();

        const newUserAccount = await account.create(ID.unique(),
            email,
            password,
            `${firstName} ${lastName}`);

        const session = await account.createEmailPasswordSession(
            email,
            password
        );

        cookies().set("appwrite-session", session.secret, {
            path: "/",
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: "strict",
            secure: true,
        });
        return parseStringify(newUserAccount)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error', error)
    }
}

export async function getLoggedInUser() {
    try {
        const { account } = await createSessionClient();
        const user = await account.get();
        return parseStringify(user)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export const logoutAccount = async () => {
    try {
        const { account } = await createSessionClient()
        cookies().delete('appwrite-session')
        await account.deleteSession('current')
    } catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
}

Signup and sign in is working and a session is showing in Appwrite dashboard but yet user is undefined and 'no session' error is showing.
